# Preloader to wordpress with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, preloader

Hi guys i added preloader gif to my wordpress page and it doesnt work properly
If you can help me find my mistake or help me build it other way.
Or if any of you knows any free plugin for preloading that would be better

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
     $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();
        });
```

```css
div#preloader { 
      position: absolute; 
      left: 0; 
      top: 0; 
      z-index: 999; 
      width: 100vw; 
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: visible;
      background: #333 url('http://grow-up.different.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/GrowUp-logo-2.gif') no-repeat center center; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader"></div>
```

Comment: this is a strange url: `http://grow-up.different.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/GrowUp-logo-2.gif` I cannot get this to load.

Comment: @scoopzilla this is link from my library in wordpress, you can use this URL

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/6oafgNSvv5pq8inRRINsddNEvGC3Oy5nDR4KMibEB9Ecnsm2YwYEZMMXJgCFyiwt/file

Comment: Check Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#` in your div

`<div id="preloader"></div>` instead of `<div id="#preloader"></div>`

---

```js
$(function() 
{
    $('#preloader').fadeOut(2500, function() 
    {
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

```css
div#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('http://grow-up.different.com.mk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/GrowUp-logo-2.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="preloader"></div>
```

Comment: sorry this is my mistake while writing the question, i have no # in the code, i will edit my post, thank for noticing that